# Why my particles do not appear on the top of the mesh?

Tags: mesh, particles, blend-files

So I was watching the Donut tutorial by Blender Guru and I added sprinkles as particles but it is not working as it did for him. My sprinkles spawn in the middle of the iceing and when I scale it, it does not change the position rather increases the size. I tried searching how to move particles but it is not helpful.
Blender File: [image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the negative offset on the Solidify modifier, the normals are flipped. Select the icing, enter edit mode, select all, and then pick *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate* Inside from the menu at the top:

[image: Mesh]

You will probably want to move the particle object back onto its origin point as well, as particle systems base their locations off an object's position relative to its origin.

[image: Origin]

Lastly, you will want to enable the rotation setting of the Hair Particle system to be able to randomize your sprinkles. Remember, you must adjust the "Phase" value away from default before the "Randomize Phase" will work.

[image: Random]